# SOLVED Call data every time that user enters in a page (tab based routing)

Tags: ionic-framework

I’m developing an app based on tab navigation.
ionic + stencil + typescript
I would like to make my api calls everytime that the user enters on a page but the page don’t recharge when user change tab page because of caching. there is an event that I can listen to do this operation? I need to have fresh data from api every time the user enters in tab pages.

Solution:
In the pare where I want to call the api each time the user enters the page, this code

```
@Listen('ionViewWillEnter')
listenIon() {
    this.userData = undefined;
    loadUserData(this.userId);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi This will help you.

[ionic Page lifecycle](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/lifecycle#ionic-page-events).

I'm mostly using in angular "ionViewWillEnter" to do something when page view. It runs every time.

Cheers.

Comment: thank you, listen to ionViewWillEnter works

Comment: My Pleasure. If you need any help in ionic feel free to message me. Thank you.